# Ubuntu on a Windows ME PC

Tags: distro-recommendation

Will Ubuntu ore Lubuntu work on my old Windows ME PC, or will I have to try an older edition of L/Ubuntu -If so what version?

Answer (score 0):

Try Lubuntu 13.04 32-bit or Ubuntu GNOME 13.04 32-bit, if they don't work, you probably need something called a non-PAE kernal, so install Lubuntu 12.04 32-bit and then run the following commands in a Terminal (press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T`):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:prof7bit/fake-pae
sudo do-release-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

That should upgrade you to Lubuntu 13.04. You can then install Ubuntu GNOME for 'fuller' Ubuntu experience (it has the Ubuntu system tray in the top-right).

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

To remove Lubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get remove lubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: As a comment: One of the great things about Ubuntu is that you can run a fully up-to-date OS on extremely old PCs thanks to lightweight flavors, if you stick to ME you would be 13 years out-of-date OS-wise :/

Answer (score 0):

If your old system hardware is supported by Ubuntu then you should be able to install it without any issue.

Look at [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/installation-guide/i386/ch02.html) for 13.04 Or [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/hardware-req.html) for 12.04 Or [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/hardware-req.html) for 10.04 system requirements

All links are for x86 systems, which I would guess is yours

Comment: Well, yes that is the simple answer, but I personally haven't been able to run full-blown Unity on a Windows XP laptop so I would recommend getting a more up-to-date lightweight distro (Unity would only work with Unity 2D which is 12.04 which is technically out-of-date and 10.04 is also more out-of-date).

Comment: That is correct, Unity interface has higher system requirements than actually specified by Canonical guys for OS itself. But IMHO lack of unity interface should be not big issue (I personally don't like that interface). I am just giving OP links so he can look at h/w requirements by himself and decide which distro he want to try.

Comment: You're not suggesting distros, you're suggesting out-of-date versions which is NOT a good idea when you're trying to give a good impression of Ubuntu. ( IMHO Unity is brilliant :P )

Comment: If you read question OP is open for old distros. Plus I am suggesting Ubuntu distros only because this is Ubuntu forum !! And without knowing his actual H/W specs I can only point him to locations where he can compare h/w requirements not actually recommend distro.

Comment: (L/X/K/Ed)Ubuntu(GNOME/Studio/Kylin) 13.04 are all official Ubuntu :P And OP is open to Lubuntu and Lubuntu that is up-to-date (better software) > Ubuntu that is out-of-date (more official interface) IMO

Comment: Yes and I would think that all of them will have same system requirement since they are based on Ubuntu,(with some degree of variation) so I've included only Ubuntu links.